# Trouble using Angular material Bottom Sheet control

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Just trying to get the angular material library working for the bottom sheet control. I've followed the example they say, putting the $mdBottomSheet dependency in my controller injection, but it seems that component can't find something it needs. The error I get is

> Exception was thrown at line 4146, column 11 in
>   http://localhost:58270/Scripts/angular.js 0x800a139e - JavaScript
>   runtime error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   $mdBottomSheetProvider <- $mdBottomSheet <- SEFlexJobsController

My controller

```
app.controller("SEFlexJobsController", ["$scope", "$http", "$modal", "$log", "$element", "$rootScope", "AlertsService", "AuthService", "SEJobService", "$interval", "$mdBottomSheet", function ($scope, $http, $modal, $log, $element, $rootScope, AlertsService, AuthService, SEJobService, $interval, $mdBottomSheet) {
    $rootScope.closeAlert = AlertsService.closeAlert;
    $scope.AuthService = AuthService;
    $scope.SEJobService = SEJobService;
    $scope.disableControls = false;
    $scope.isBusy = false;
    $scope.totalItems = 0;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.recordsPerPage = 10;
    $scope.fetchingData = false;
    $scope.tableStateRef = null;
    $scope.showListBottomSheet = function ($event) {
        $scope.alert = '';
        $mdBottomSheet.show({
            templateUrl: 'bottom-sheet-list-template.html',
            controller: 'ListBottomSheetCtrl',
            targetEvent: $event
        }).then(function (clickedItem) {
            $scope.alert = clickedItem['name'] + ' clicked!';
        });
    };
}
]);
```

I am including the material includes with the following in my BundleConfig

```
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css",
                      "~/Scripts/angular-loading/loading-bar.css",
                      "~/Scripts/nya-bs-select/nya-bs-select.min.css",
                      "~/Content/angular-ui-switch.css",
                      "~/Content/angular-material.min.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular")
                .Include("~/Scripts/angular.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js",
                    "~/Scripts/AngularApp/app.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular.animate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular.aria.js",
                    "~/Scripts/angular.material.js")
                .IncludeDirectory("~/app", "*.js", true)
                .Include("~/Scripts/smart-table/smart-table.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular-loading/loading-bar.js",
                "~/Scripts/nya-bs-select/nya-bs-select.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/moment.js"));
```

The only thing on the example I don't have is a module include as I am not using modules

In the example on the website https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/bottomSheet

```
angular.module('bottomSheetDemo1', ['ngMaterial'])
```

so I am not including ngMaterial anywhere. Can I put this in my constructor along with $mdBottomSheet? I tried it at my ng-app include level but it couldn't find ngMaterial

app module below

```
var app = angular.module('PortalXApp', ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap", "ui.bootstrap.showErrors", "smart-table", "angular-loading-bar", "nya.bootstrap.select", "uiSwitch"]);

app.constant('USER_ROLES', {
    jobMasterDelete: "jobMasterDelete",
    jobMasterEdit: "jobMasterEdit",
    jobMasterView: "jobMasterView",

    jobTemplateDelete: "jobTemplateDelete",
    jobTemplateEdit: "jobTemplateEdit",
    jobTemplateRun: "jobTemplateRun",
    jobTemplateView: "jobTemplateView"
});

app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    //initialize get if not there
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
    }
    //disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
    // extra
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
}]);
```

Comment: Have you included the Angular Material Javascript in your `index.html`?

Comment: Have just updated my question with the details

Comment: in your controller code what is `app` (where it says `app.controller(...`)?

Comment: Added the app definition above

Comment: If I include "ngMaterial" in that list of modules to depend on in app, I get the error - Module 'ngMaterial' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the angular material JS file? I noticed you load a file called `angular.material.js`, where usually the name is like `angular-material.js`

Comment: :'-( It's always the basic errors that catch you out. Nicely spotted, would have been going around in circles for days.